# Is it good practice to emit socket event inside event listener/event on server side

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is this correct way/ best practice to emit socket.io event inside another event?

```
// join room
socket.on("joinRoom", async() => {
   ...
})


// create room and then join room
socket.on("createRoom", async() => {
   ...
   socket.emit("joinRoom")
   ...
}
```

Comment: `.emit()` sends a message to the OTHER end of the socket.io connection.  You do not `.emit()` to yourself with socket.io.  It's not clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish here - if you explain that better, then we could probably help more specifically.

Comment: @jfriend00 @jfriend00 Hi, thanks for answering, I have two seperate event listeners on server side : "joinRoom" and "createRoom" that interacts with mongoDB database. In my chat app if client side is creating a new room, on the server side I want to `socket.on("joinRoom")` right after `socket.on("createRoom")`.   "createRoom" stores new room data in the room model in mongoDB, "joinRoom" sends a welcome message to the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

`socket.emit()` sends a message to the OTHER end of the socket.io connection. You do not `.emit()` to yourself with socket.io. When `socket.emit("joinRoom")` is sent from your server, it sends a message to the client, not to your server. So, that won't do what you want it to do.

You can put the code from `joinRoom` into a shared function and you can call it from both the `joinRoom` event handler and from the `createRoom` event handler.

You could also combine the logic for `joinRoom` and `createRoom` into one event where you pass an argument if you want the room created before joining.  Then, the "join" code is right there locally for both operations.